# Select a cell by UIButton - CollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using collectionView, and I customized the collectionViewCell in a separate class with type (collectionViewCell). I want to perform an animation when user clicks on a cell. So, I created a UIButton in collectionViewCell and I customized it to cover the whole cell.

```
       button = UIButton(frame: self.frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "scaleToSmall", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    self.addSubview(button)
```

Right now, the animation works perfectly, but the issue is I lost the ability select the cell, and the function **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** does not call anymore

I found out how to get the indexPath of the cell that has clicked,

**But** how can I call **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** again and tell it this cell is selected in order to perform the next action (segue to another ViewController) ???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What about creating a custom segue that does a custom animation:  [tutorial](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2013/10/13/custom-segues/).

Comment: Why do you need the button? Can't you just animate at function didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you created a button that covers the whole cell, if I have that right. Because of that, didSelectRowAtIndexPath won't do anything because that button is covering the whole cell. Take the Twitter app, for example. You can tap on the cell to open the tweet or you can tap on the user's profile image to open their profile. In this case, it's like you have the profile picture button covering the whole cell. Maybe you can set the animation in didSelectRowAtIndexPath or make the button smaller.

Hope this helps!